# Download headers somehow inserting 18 lines of whitespace

Tags: php, csv, header, download

I am trying to serve up a dynamically generated csv file.  For some reason when I get the file, there are 18 empty rows preceding the data.  I don't have any space between the headers I define and the csv data I'm sending.  If I write the data to a file on the server, it does not get these empty rows.  However, if I write the file and then try to serve it to the user, the empty lines come back.  So I'm wondering if perhaps I've messed up the headers, or if perhaps there is another issue I'm not thinking of:

```
function generate_csv($source_type, $include_unpublished = FALSE) {

   // retrieve data from DB
   ....

   // start up headers
   $csv_name = "$source_type-$data_set-csv_" . date('Y-m-d') . '.csv';
   header('Content-Type: text/x-comma-separated-values');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
   header('Cache-Control: private', false); // required for certain browser
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $csv_name . '"'); 

   // send csv data
   print $csv_data;

} //end function
```

Disclaimer: I asked this question at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27649/extra-empty-rows-when-serving-csv-file, but it dosn't seem to be drupal-specific and there weren't many ideas coming up over there..

Comment: Do you use output buffering? When this is the case, the empty rows may also be somewhere _before_ where you set the headers.

Comment: Good point.  Unfortunately, I'm not doing any ob.

Comment: You have mentioned, that you are using Drupal. So you are _sure_, that no output buffering is active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be problem with files that you are including. Every whitespace more than one newline after php closing tag `?>` is sent to the browser.

Best solution is to get rid of this closing tags in every php file.

Other option will be to remove only unnecessary new lines from them or to bufer output and disregard it before serving file.

Comment: +1 true. Also, it outputs content before `<?php` (invisible BOMs for example).

Comment: The files I've looked over don't include a ?> tag. Is there a simple way to list the files that were included during the php cycle?  This is a module within the Drupal CMS, so I'm not even sure what files are being used during this process..

Comment: @KingCrunch - thanks that did it.  Someone had built a sample module from an online tutorial that had a bunch of ?> tags in it.  Even though it had nothing to do with my code, the module was enabled and Drupal was loading it, and the whitespace was added before my content.  There were 140 files included, but the one named MyModule had a bit of a smell to it..  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this lines "hang" in an output buffer, that were started some time before. This way you can set headers without the good old "headers already sent"-error, but this content will be send to the browser when flushing the buffer anyway.

Try

```
ob_clean();
print $csv_data;
```

http://php.net/ob-clean

Comment: Thanks @kingCrunch, you save a lot of time.