# How to use php to write to a file

Tags: php, csv

I have a form and when I hit submit, I need the data that I posted to be saved to a csv file.  The code below generates a syntax error elsewhere in my script but I know the problem lies somewhere here. Can someone please explain my mistake?

```
//Store all data into variables ready to save
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $ID = $_POST['gameID'];
        $GameName = $_POST['gameName'];
        $GameCost = $_POST['gameCost'];
        $Days = $_POST['days'];
        $Total = $_POST['total'];
        $DateFrom = $_POST['reservationStart'];
        $DateTo = $_POST['DateEnd'];
        $StudentName = $_POST['studentName'];


//Saving the booking
   $csv_file = 'loans.csv';
   $csv_handle = fopen($csv_file,'a');
   $csv_item = "\"$ID\",\"$GameName\",\"$GameCost\",\"$Days\",\"$Total\",\"$DateFrom\",\"$DateTo\",\"$StudentName\"\n";
   fwrite($csv_handle, $csv_item);
   fclose($csv_handle);
```

Comment: check your file permissions. Can PHP write to the file?

Comment: missing closing brace after $StudentName  (your IF statement)

Comment: Consider using fputcsv() and sibling functions, since they will handle formatting and escaping natively for you.

Comment: I prefer tab delimited.  Comma delimited has too many issue to deal with like escaping double quotes with double double quotes `""`.  Tab delimited requires no escaping in most every instance.  Easier to code in the tabs too. `"$ID\t$GameName\t$GameCost\t$Days\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket for your if

```
//Store all data into variables ready to save
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $ID = $_POST['gameID'];
            $GameName = $_POST['gameName'];
            $GameCost = $_POST['gameCost'];
            $Days = $_POST['days'];
            $Total = $_POST['total'];
            $DateFrom = $_POST['reservationStart'];
            $DateTo = $_POST['DateEnd'];
            $StudentName = $_POST['studentName'];
    } // THIS CLOSING BRACE

    //Saving the booking
       $csv_file = 'loans.csv';
       $csv_handle = fopen($csv_file,'a');
       $csv_item = "\"$ID\",\"$GameName\",\"$GameCost\",\"$Days\",\"$Total\",\"$DateFrom\",\"$DateTo\",\"$StudentName\"\n";
       fwrite($csv_handle, $csv_item);
       fclose($csv_handle);
```

Comment: Damn! Your right the curly brace is missing, I had commented it out.  However, it needs to go after fclose($csv_handle) otherwise I get undefined variable. Cant believe I wasted a question on this...ahhhhh.

Comment: Out of interest, why does the line write on row 9 of my csv file and not row 1. It offends my perfectionist streak???

Comment: Lol. no bother happy days! Tick if it helped!

Comment: @Student heres answer to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048372/download-headers-somehow-inserting-18-lines-of-whitespace

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `fputcsv`:

```
$csv_file = 'loans.csv';
$csv_handle = fopen($csv_file, 'a'); // a
fputcsv($csv_handle, array($ID, $GameName, $GameCost, $Days, $total, $DateFrom, $DateTo, $StudentName));
fclose($csv_handle);
```

The problem is most likely an error in escaping the input, but `fputcsv` takes care of that for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to the end of file, try this:

```
 file_put_contents($csv_file, $csv_item, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

or

```
  $csv_handle = fopen($csv_file,'a');
  fwrite($csv_handle, $csv_item);
  fclose($csv_handle);
```

Comment: Interesting - whats LOCK_EX ?

Comment: LOCK_EX - Acquire an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the writing.